# How to build path to route in Laravel with parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have this route

```
Route::get('org/edit/{id}/', ['as' => 'org.edit', 'uses' => 'OrgController@edit']);
```

And then create a link to this route by using Laravel Blade template:

```
<a href="{{ route('org.edit', [$org->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
```

What I expect to see:

```
/org/edit/123/
```

What I get:

```
/org/edit?123
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing it as a key value pair.

```
{{ route('org.edit', ['id' => $org->id]) }}
```

Comment: You don't happen to have another route named `org.edit` which doesn't take an id parameter do you?

Comment: yep. i had post route to /org/edit (without {id} parameter) and after removing - all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Dmitriy,
in this case you can try two ways.

```
{{ route('org.edit', ['id' => $org->id,]) }}

{{ route('org.edit', $org->id) }}
```

Check this out. :)